# Predicting/calculating congestion in telecom network

Tags: networking, mobile, telecommunication, congestion-control

I have an application installed at my phone which is providing below details every minute:  - Bandwidth , -Packet loss ,-signal strength,- RTT for google.com every minute.
I am trying to predict congestion based on these 4 attribute , but some how it doesn't look accurate to me , previously i have only used bandwidth .
I want predict congestion at any point more appropriately , appreciate any recommendations .

Comment: I saw you reverted some of my edits back. Just to explain my edit: **signatures and thanks are not welcome in SO**, they are nothing but noise to people who read the post. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed). And if I recall correctly, the pronoun for the first person in English is still capitalized **I**, not **i**.

Comment: My intent was to make correction in my own post , what you edited wasn't looking fine to me .  So , i just made changes to my first post. For thanks and signatures i made the necessary corrections.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying you are trying to measure network 'responsiveness', and from these measurements get a sense of how congested the network is. You also mention you want to predict which I guess means you want to make an estimate of the future 'responsiveness' based on your measurements and observations.

The items you are measuring look sensible, although you may want to include jitter if you are interested in VoIP or other real time streamed media.

The issue you have is that there are many variables which can effect your measurements, for example:

- congestion in the radio cell you are in at the time
- congestion in the backhaul network
- delays in the server you are using to measure the RTT
- congestion or faults with the particular APN your mobile is using to access data services
- network faults

As some of these can be irregularly occurring but can have a large impact, it is quite hard to build up an accurate view of the overall network 'responsiveness' with a single handset. For example your local cell may be busy or have a problem but others users of Google.com in other cells will have perfectly good response, or Google.com may be busy or delayed and other users in your cell accessing a different server may again have perfectly good response.

It would likely be useful for you to look at some of the generally available web speedtest applications to see the type of information they provide - they have the advantage of being able to gather results from many thousands of users, and also generally have access to the servers to understand any issues on that side.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve it might be that a combination of measurements from one of the general speedtest services, combined with your own measurements will give you enough data to draw some sort of meaningful conclusions.

Comment: Appreciate your thought on jitter.
I do agree , there are multiple factor to look at , but we need to derive a close relationship between the attributes i am tracking with the cell congestion at that point of time.
Even though there are number of apps like speedtest , opensignal (andriod)  available but no one actual gives any idea about cell congestion .

Comment: That is going to be tricky without access to the operators data. For example you could have several test phones in different cells, but you still could not be sure how the cells are back hauled and connected to your final destination, and the perceived delay might be introduced there.

Comment: BTW, you can get (very expensive) specialised test equipment which will allow you observe the low level (e.g. MAC-d and RRC) 3G protocols that control the radio bearer and that are used in congestion control etc, but I don't know of any Android/iPhone apps or API's etc with access to these layers. If you find some let us know...